# Expression labelling to annotation - ArcMap to CAD

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling

I have point feature layer (more than 100).
My task is labelling that point and convert annotation (I use ArcMap) then export that to DWG format

I use this script to labelling :

```
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
... for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
...     if lyr.isFeatureLayer:
...         f = arcpy.ListFields(lyr,"*grid_dec*")
...         if f:
...             lyr.labelClasses[0].expression = '"{}" & 
    (left([grid_dec],1)) & " " & "<SUB>" & (right( 
    [grid_dec],1)) & "</SUB>" & "{}"'.format("<FNT size = '17'> 
    <CLR blue = '255'>","</CLR></FNT>")
...             lyr.showLabels = True
...         else:
...             print lyr.name
...     lyr.visible = True
...     
... arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

It works, but the problem is, I just realize when I convert to annotation it become text not number (value in the field), so when I export to DWG it become text, Here is the screeshot

[image]

If I use simple expression for example :

```
 lyr.labelClasses[0].expression = round([field],2)
```

It is still a number in string field, but I need to use subscript function to be applied at my number and the result should be become a number, so any clue or workaround?

this is screenshot of my solution that ive made

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure annotation is always text in ArcGIS.

Comment: i know, its always text, what i mean is, if yu use simple expression like [field] where your field is a number value, in the annotation field called "textstring" will be number even the "textstring" field is a string type, in short, even its string field we can write number on it, my problem is if i put space or vbCrLf in the expression it will be read as "enter" but when i put subscript function it will be <SUB> on the field named "textstring" like the screenshot

Comment: Sorry, still unclear.

Comment: im sorry , maybe i didnt explain clearly. my point is, in my script - label expression statement, if i use vbCrLf or vbnewline , the result in CAD layer (label to anno to dwg) it become new line, like if you press "enter" after typing, but i need format subscript and i use "<SUB>", it success in arcmap and create subscript effect between 2 number, but in CAD in become (let say value 4 and 5) 4 "<SUB>" 5, so the subscript effect itself didnt work....my question is how i use subscript effect in annotation layer after i convert into DWG

Comment: but i figured it out, turns out you can use vbCrLf to create "enter" effect between 2 character, then you add field in your layer with name "FontLeading"  to control the lenght of your "enter" effect, i put some screenshot in edited question, thanks